# Not able to make a valid Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to `Regex` and started playing with it a few days ago. But now I am stuck at one `string`.

For example:
I have this string -> `<a href="http://somelink.com", example1="", example2="">`

I am trying to `Replace` all of that string from `<a` to `>` but I want to keep the `href` part and the link. I have been going over this at https://regex101.com but to no avail. The `Regex` pattern that I am trying is `<a(\s?)(?!.*?href=\".*?\").*?>`. This pattern does not find anything in the string. I am using `C#`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Update:

The actual string looks like

```
<a href="http://somelink.com", example1="", example2="">
```

and I want to remove this part

```
, example1="", example2=""
```

But then I want to keep this part

```
<a href="http://somelink.com">
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have at start and what you want to have as a result?

Comment: Please read https://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can search by this:

```
<a[^>]*?(href="[^"]+")[^>]*>
```

and replace by this:

```
<a $1>
```

[Run the source](http://ideone.com/c3y3q2)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HbBDCl/2)

Comment: I don't get why somebody downvoted me, would like to know the reason for downvote and resolve it

Comment: what are the instances ?

Comment: it selects all of this `<p>The <a href="http://some.com/tag/modern-family/"><em>Modern Family</em></a> star found herself <a href="http://some.com/style/explains-her-most-controversial-outfits/">defending her wardrobe choices</a> (yet again) after posting a photo from a night out with her &ldquo;squad,&rdquo; when she wore a lingerie-like top and booty-shorts with knee-high boots.</p>
`

Answer (score 0):

This might work `<a(?:.*?)(href=\"(.*?)\").*?>`
Group(1) = `href="..."` and Group(2) = `link`

Demo https://regex101.com/r/Yz0kPc/1
Added more attributes https://regex101.com/r/Yz0kPc/2